# How to put a function as an argument in C?

Tags: c, function, object, arguments

I would like to execute a function given in the paramater of a function. Let me explain with an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int object() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}

int run_func( int a_lambda_function() ) {
    a_lambda_function();
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    run_func( object() );
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I want to run "object()" in the parameters of "run_func(**int a_lambda_function()**").
When I run it, It returns an error. How would I achieve this is full C?

Restrictions I have:

1. **Absolutly No C++  allowed**.

Comment: You're asking for C, so it's pretty obvious that C++ is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, But some people don't check if it's C or C++. There are a lot of questions that have C++ answers when asked for pure C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions can be passed as arguments or stored into variables as function pointers.

The definition for a function pointer compatible with your `object` function is `int (*funcp)()` ie: a pointer to a function taking an unspecified number of arguments and returning `int`.

In modern C, functions with an unspecified number of arguments are not used anymore, and functions taking no arguments must be declared with a `(void)` argument list.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int object(void) {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}

int run_func(int (*a_lambda_function)(void)) {
    return a_lambda_function();  // can also write (*a_lambda_function)()
}

int main() {
    return run_func(object);
}
```